# Squeezing. Skill check (in a skill challenge)?

Tags: dnd-4e, skill-challenge

I am preparing a skill challenge for my group. On a fail branch they are going to hit a wall that they can squeeze through (group check) or can back track Athletics. What skill would I use for squeezing quickly? Would it be athletics or acrobatics? Or none at all.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd suggest that acrobatics is more appropriate because it has to do with flexibility and tumbling and things that would be more appropriate to squeezing.

But that's only if you *want* to require a skill check there. Squeezing as normal does not require a check *but* if a character must do so quickly or with a certain amount of finesse a check is definitely appropriate.

If you group is generally *weak* on acrobatics, but is strong on athletics, offering a higher DC athletics check instead might be appropriate. I could even see a case made for endurance if your characters don't mind taking some physical torture in place of finesse.

Comment: I like this answer but want to get other opinions before I accept. The challenge is they are chasing a person so time is of the essence.

Comment: I guess the athlethics guys could jump over the wall, the endurance ones could circle the building and... yeah, the acrobatic PCs can have squeezing as an option.

Comment: @Zachiel whatever story you choose to surround it with :)

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like the activity of Sqeezing through a small space fits under a type of thing called [Contortion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contortion).

(From the page):

> Contortion (sometimes contortionism) is an unusual form of physical
>   display which involves the dramatic bending and flexing of the human
>   body. Contortion is often part of **acrobatics** and circus acts. In
>   general, "contortionists" have unusual natural flexibility, which is
>   then enhanced through acrobatic training, or they put themselves
>   through intense, vigorous and painful training to gain this
>   flexibility.

So, as you can see, Acrobatics would be the correct skill.